# How to plot list of lists on different heights of Y-axis?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

By having a list of lists in Python I need to plot them (using Matplotlib and Python) one list under another using a step on the Y-axis.
E.g: `ll = [[1,2,3], [0,3,4]]`

For `ll`, the list of lists, the step on the Y-axis would be 4 (the biggest value).
An offset is initialized to 0.
With every list plotted the offset will be increased with the step on the Y-axis.
The values on the X-axis would be `1,2,3` for every list, because there are 3 points in every sublist.
The values on the Y-axis would be `1,2,3`(offset is 0) for the first list and `4,6,7` for the second list, I have added the offset(0+step(4) = 4) to every element.

For the next element the offset would be 8. This value would be added to each element in the 3rd list(if it would exists in the example) and so on...
Also I need the points from the same list to be connected.
`ll` could contain more than only 2 lists.
The plot would look like:
[image: Plotted list of lists]

The code I have written:

```
x = np.arange(0, len(list_of_lists[0]))
y = list_of_lists[0]

step_on_y = max([item for sublist in list_of_lists for item in sublist])

lines = []
rows = 0
for list_in in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_lists[list_in]) - 1):
        pair = [(x[i], list_of_lists[list_in][i] + rows), (x[i + 1], list_of_lists[list_in][i+1] + rows)]
        lines.append(pair)
    rows = rows + step_on_y

linecoll = matcoll.LineCollection(lines)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_collection(linecoll)
print(len(x), len(list_of_lists)*len(list_of_lists[0]))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.ylim(0, 30)

plt.show()
```

The result I get:
[image: The result I get]

How could I get the desired result? What should I modify in my code?

Comment: You describe what you would like to get, show your code and a plot, which afaics has what you want. So - what's the question?

Comment: The code doesn't work for more than two lists. What changes should I make in the code to work for any number of lists in list.

Comment: Why exactly are the plotted data for the second list 4,6,7, when the list says 1,3,4?  You should describe explicitly your procedure; giving us an example and letting us figure out the underlying algorithm will not motivate people to work on your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly positive you are making this a lot more convoluted than it should.

Here is a piece of code that should do what you are looking for
(I added an horizontal grey dashed line to show where the plot of the next 'list' is starting) 
PS: In this example i'm using the max value of the previous list as the offset for the next one to ensure no overlap between plots, but you can easily make it constant or customize it

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ll = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [1,1,1], [4,5,6]]
c = ['k','r','b','g','c']

x = np.arange(0, len(ll[0]))
a = np.array( ll)


step = 0
ax = plt.subplot()
for n,l in enumerate( a):
    ax.plot(x, l + step)
    ax.scatter(x, l + step)
    ax.axhline(y=step, color='#cccccc', dashes=[5,3])

    step += np.max(l)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked as expected! I have also modified ax.scatter(x, l + step) into ax.scatter(x, l + step, s=1) to lower the size of a dot.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to plot all the lines in one plot command, including the circles.

Therefore I use a numpy array representation of `ll` and add the offsets to all the sublists starting from the second.
The array of the offsets is just the cumulative sum of the maximum values of each sublist.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ll = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2]]
arr = np.array(ll).T

arr[:, 1:] += np.cumsum(np.max(arr[:, :-1], axis=0))

plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], arr, '-o', mfc='w')
```

[image]